# Core Data document-based app: saves, but cannot load

Tags: cocoa, core-data, load, save, document-based

So long story short, I'm working on a Cocoa CoreData Document-Based app (my first time working with Cocoa), I haven't written a single line of code, everything is done through bindings and the default code and everything works great, I can enter data, display it, etc (it's all being run through an array controller of my coredata object).  The only thing I have an issue with is that I can save the document, but I can't load from it, that is, when I use the built in save function it will save a file that contains the information I have entered (I saved as XML and checked, it's all there), but when I use the built in open function, it just opens a blank document.  I've looked around tutorials for coredata but haven't been able to find anything, they just say that save and open should work on their own.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your open menu is not bound to the document controller correct. You probably sending a new, instead of open.